How is Imperfect Contrition of Catholic Catechism justified with reference to Jn 14:15?
We hear Jesus saying in Jn 14:15:

If you love Me, keep My commandments.

Elsewhere, we see Jesus telling the rich man, in Mtt 19:17,before naming some of the Ten Commandments:

..if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

Catechism of the Catholic Church teaches about two types of contrition under the Sacrament of Reconciliation :
(i)Perfect contrition – An act made out of love for God, and..
(ii) Imperfect contrition – An act made for some other motive such as fear of Hell.
The Catechism further explains that either type of contrition is sufficient in order to make a confession and have our sins forgiven.
Now, read Jn 14:15 in the reverse order and we have : "If you keep My commandments, you love me ; if you do not keep my commandments, you do not love me ." Doesn't that put a limitation on Imperfect Contrition which does not examine the breach of love for Jesus ?
My question therefore, is : How is Imperfect Contrition of Catholic Catechism justified with reference to Jn 14:15 ?

Examining what the Catechism actually says may be helpful.

1450 "Penance requires ... the sinner to endure all things willingly, be contrite of heart, confess with the lips, and practice complete humility and fruitful satisfaction." 1451 Among the penitent's acts contrition occupies first place. Contrition is "sorrow of the soul and detestation for the sin committed, together with the resolution not to sin again." 1452 When it arises from a love by which God is loved above all else, contrition is called "perfect" (contrition of charity). Such contrition remits venial sins; it also obtains forgiveness of mortal sins if it includes the firm resolution to have recourse to sacramental confession as soon as possible. 1453 The contrition called "imperfect" (or "attrition") is also a gift of God, a prompting of the Holy Spirit. It is born of the consideration of sin's ugliness or the fear of eternal damnation and the other penalties threatening the sinner (contrition of fear). Such a stirring of conscience can initiate an interior process which, under the prompting of grace, will be brought to completion by sacramental absolution. By itself however, imperfect contrition cannot obtain the forgiveness of grave sins, but it disposes one to obtain forgiveness in the sacrament of Penance. 1454 The reception of this sacrament ought to be prepared for by an examination of conscience made in the light of the Word of God. The passages best suited to this can be found in the Ten Commandments, the moral catechesis of the Gospels and the apostolic Letters, such as the Sermon on the Mount and the apostolic teachings.

So contrition generally is defined as "sorrow of the soul and detestation for the sin committed, together with the resolution not to sin again." Both perfect and imperfect contrition must conform to this definition. Perfect and imperfect contrition are distinct in their motivation. On the one hand, perfect contrition is motivated by love of God above all else, and on the other, imperfect contrition is motivated by something besides this, and is a kind of contrition of fear. Note also that the Catechism says that perfect contrition by itself can obtain the forgiveness of sins, while imperfect contrition can only dispose one to receive the sacramental graces of the sacrament of confession.
Another distinction needs to be made between extraordinary and ordinary graces. Ordinary graces are the ones that come to us through the sacraments. God has guaranteed them by His own Word. Whenever we participate in the sacraments, grace is certainly given. However, one must also be disposed to receive grace in order for the grace received to be efficacious. What the catechism is saying here is that imperfection contrition is sufficient to dispose someone to receive the graces of the confessional. However, that does not mean one is perfectly disposed. You will find all sorts of writings in the Church on disposition, and how one may be more or less disposed by virtue, interior disposition, education, etc. to receive certain graces.
Perfect contrition, on the other hand, is an extraordinary grace. It is not always promised, and not always received when sought. One must also be disposed to receive this grace if one is to receive it well, just as with ordinary graces.
Now, the question asks how imperfect contrition is justified in light of Scripture which tells the faithful to keep God's commands if they love Him. I take this to mean that some people think the doctrine of imperfect contrition contradicts this commandment. It is difficult to see how exactly that might be the case if we're speaking of strictly logical contradiction, since the given Scripture is a commandment, and the Church does not teach the faithful to violate this commandment, for She tells the faithful both that they must love God, and also that they must keep His commandments. Neither does the doctrine of imperfect contrition state that the faithful need not love God, but merely that they may be saved without a perfect love of God above all else. Love of God is still necessary. Reading the commandment backwards doesn't help us to understand that there may be a logical contradiction, since the semantic value of the commandment is changed in doing so (the converse is formed: if you keep my commands, you love me; converses do not always hold even when the conditional statements from which they are formed are true).
Perhaps the doctrine of imperfect contrition violates the spirit of this commandment? The spirit of the commandment given seems to be twofold: one, that Christians ought to love God, and, therefore, keep His commandments on account of their love for Him.
But a man who has committed sins has already violated the commandment. Whether he loves God or not, and to what degree, is irrelevant. Hence, both perfect and imperfect contrition already assume that the penitent has violated the second prong of this call. He has already violated the charge to keep God's commands. One might reasonably infer that the sinner does not love God, and to be sure, the sinner at least does not love God perfectly, since, if he did, he would keep the commands of the Lord perfectly. So, when an imperfect man turns back towards God and seeks forgiveness for having failed to keep His commands, there is an implicit love of God shown forth in this act. The sinner essentially says "Lord, I have not loved you, and thus have sinned. But, I hate my sin and want to love you." Perhaps this sinner is motivated out of a newfound perfect love for God, or, more commonly, out of a fear of punishment.
Indeed, the common motivation for imperfect contrition is fear of hell,  but what is hell? The Catechism defines hell as eternal separation from God. It calls this the "chief punishment" of hell (CCC 1035). But one only fears to be separated from that which he loves. If he does not love something, he is indifferent if he should be separated from it (and if he hates it, he should be happy to be so separated). The degree to which he fears separation will tell you the degree to which he loves the thing in question. If he fears separation from the thing completely, then he loves it perfectly. If he fears separation only to a degree, then he loves the thing imperfectly, or he does not love it above all else. Yet he still loves it somewhat. Hence, imperfect contrition motivated by the fear of hell seems to entail at least an imperfect love of God on the part of the penitent.
What of other motivations for imperfect contrition? The catechism also mentions the "ugliness of sin." St. Thomas Aquinas mentions that a gloss on Psalm 103:15 calls grace, which is lost on account of mortal sin, "a certain beauty of the soul" (ST II-I Q110 A2 s.c.). Now, this beauty of the soul, which is grace, ought to be contrasted with sin as a certain ugliness (or lack of beauty) of the soul. So, a motivation for imperfect contrition would be one's revulsion at the ugliness of one's own soul, or, put another way, at the lack of grace in it.
But grace is also "a participation in the life of God" (CCC 1997). So we see here, too, that this motivation entails a kind of imperfect love for God, too, in a similar way that the fear of hell does. If one is repulsed by one's own lack of grace, then one is repulsed by one's own lack of participation in the life of God. But no one is repulsed by that which he loves, and a lack is just a negation of a positive quality. Thus, if one is repulsed by a lack of something, it is again on account of his love for that thing that he is so repulsed by its lack. Hence, a love for participation in the life of God, and therefore a love indirectly for God Himself, is present in the imperfect contrition motivated by the ugliness of sin.
So it would seem that any act of imperfect contrition bears the mark of at least an implicit and imperfect, but still present, love of God.
